# Weak sequential completeness

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It is obvious that reflexive spaces are weakly sequentially complete. Can we have a kind of a converse to this fact? Is there a non-reflexive Banach space $X$ such that both $X$ and $X^*$ are weakly sequentially complete? Note that $X$ cannot be a Banach lattice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On page 12 of [this paper](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~kacena/pub/seq_right.pdf), it's stated that the Bourgain-Delbaen space (citation in the linked paper) is an infinite dimensional Schur space whose dual is weakly sequentially complete. Schur spaces are weakly sequentially complete and non-reflexive if infinite dimensional (see [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=Banach+space+X+weakly+sequentially+complete+kalton&source=bl&ots=ZqTPBY7gP9&sig=FpTWKynrBmNzl5BTVaFyncyWqR0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wXgLUt0cpMLZBYHZgagK&ved=0CDEQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=Banach%20space%20X%20weakly%20sequentially%20complete%20kalton&f=false) for a proof of these facts).

(It should be noted that by Rosenthal's $\ell_1$-Theorem, a weakly sequentially complete Banach space is either reflexive or contains a copy of $\ell_1$.)